# Polygons crash kernel?

Tags: graphics, crash, polygons

Having some problems Generating random `Polygons` and then filtering by `Area`, specifically filter out degenerated polygons with undefined `Area` is crashing the kernel in 12.0.

```
randomThirdPoints[n_] := Table[1/3 {RandomChoice[{0,1,2,3}],RandomChoice[{0,1,2,3}]},{n}]
```

Here are some random 4-gons in the unit square:

```
randomPolygons4 := Table[Polygon[randomThirdPoints[4]], 100];
```

This step is consistently crashing kernel:

```
randomPolygons4 // Map[Area]
```

similarly if using `Select`, `AssociationMap` and also using `RegionQ` instead of `Area`.

Are there some safer options? [Ref Page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Polygon.html) doesn't seem to help.

Comment: It's not the mapping that's the problem, it's just that the `Area` function crashes for some polygons. You `SeedRandom` when you experiment so that the problem appears consistently. For example, using `RandomSeed[1]`, you'll see that `randomPolygons4[[39]] // Area` crashes the kernel. The polygon looks like this: `Polygon[{{1/3, 1/3}, {0, 0}, {1/3, 1/3}, {0, 2/3}}]` This seems like a problem for WRI.

Comment: C.E. Thanks for replicating. Yes I used Map to sample a cross-section. Will report to support. Any known workaround for randomly generated polygons?

Comment: It would be better if you list polygons that crash the kernel and then ask "how can I find a workaround for these polygons?" It would make the question clearer and easier to answer.

Comment: @C.E, I think you identified the issue, it seems confined to polygons with repeated points. Using `safePointSets = 
  Table[randomThirdPoints[4], 100] // Select[DuplicateFreeQ]` and then `safePointSets // Map[Polygon] // Map[Area]` seems to work.

Comment: ok, I undeleted my answer.

Comment: It shouldn't crash. This gives `Undefined`: `Area@Polygon[{{0, 2/3}, {1/3, 2/3}, {0, 2/3}}]` but add a point and it crashes: `Area@Polygon[{{0, 2/3}, {1/3, 2/3}, {0, 2/3}, {2/3, 0}}]`

Comment: @MichaelE2, I filed a ticket w/ support. I'm not sure what you mean by "shouldn't" crash. Nothing should crash - the exception that duplicate vertices are not handled should be caught and surfaced to the caller.

Comment: I suppose I meant it shouldn't crash.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "possible issues" section of the documentation for `Polygon` says that

> Degenerate polygons are not valid geometric regions

A degenerate polygon is a polygon that has two or more vertices which are the same.

The polygons that crash the kernel seem to be of this type. You can avoid the kernel crashes by not evaluating `Area` on such polygons, for example by using

```
If[DuplicatesFreeQ[vertices], Area[Polygon[vertices]], Undefined]
```

or you can modify your definition of `randomThirdPoints` so that it doesn't generate duplicate vertices:

```
randomThirdPoints[n_] := 1/3 RandomSample[Tuples[{0, 1, 2, 3}, 2], n]
```

Comment: I tried `randomPolygons4 // Map[DuplicateFreeQ] // Apply[And]` and always get `True` (note I edited my question to use `SetDelayed` in the definition of `randomPolygons4`)

Comment: @alancalvitti Using `DuplicateFreeQ` on polygons won't work, you have to run it on the list of vertices.

Comment: I'm still experiencing crashes, using the distinct vertex generator, when sampling say 8-gons, and calling RegionQ (possibly some are polygons with holes).

Answer (score 4):

One workaround for polygons with 4 different points:

```
Map[Area[DiscretizeGraphics[#]] &, randomPolygons4]
```

Comment: does this work for any `n` distinct points? (Because then I could filter these before calling Polygon)`

Comment: @alancalvitti Probably yes, because `DiscretizeGraphics` creates a MeshRegion.

Comment: Given currently the polygon vertices are sampled from a regular grid in unit square, how much distortion in the `Area - DiscretizedGraphics[Area]` can I expect with, say, uniformly random points in unit square?

Comment: @alancalvitti If the meshregion consists of triangles there is   no distortion I think.

Answer (score 3):

Based on C.E.'s work, vertex deduplication must be done at the point of generation, eg:

```
randomThirdPoints[n_] := Module[{pts},
    pts := Table[a {RandomChoice[{0,1,2,3}],RandomChoice[{0,1,2,3}]},{n}];
    p=pts;
    While[Not[DuplicateFreeQ[p]],p= pts]
    p
    ]
```

this generated safe `Polygon`s:

```
Table[randomThirdPoints[4], 100] // Map[DuplicateFreeQ] // Apply[And]
```

> True

`Area` works for all of these, though `Undefined still need to be filtered`:

```
Table[Polygon@randomThirdPoints[4], 20] // Map[Area]
```

> {4/27, 16/63, 1/6, 7/45, 1/3, 1/6, 1/2, Undefined, 1/9, 1/6, 2/5, \
>   4/27, 1/9, 1/18, 11/54, 1/6, 1/9, 2/9, 1/2, 1/6}

**Is there a more compact syntax?** I don't think I've used a `While` loop in 20 years.

Comment: You can use e.g. `randomThirdPoints[n_] := 1/3 RandomSample[Tuples[{0, 1, 2, 3}, 2], n]` I think, but haven't thought about it too long.

Comment: @C.E., thanks RandomSample works.